# search GitHub for projects with specific Framework & Demo

Tags: git, search, github, google-bigquery, gitlab

I'd like to search GitHub (and maybe Gitlab, Bitbucket & Co) for repositories that have a GitHub Page (meaning they should most likely have a gh_pages branch) or a demo at Firebase, Heroku etc.

Also I would like to easily search for repos which use the Angular Framework or React for example. 
I can search for [`"@angular/core" filename:package.json stars:2`](https://github.com/search?l=&q="%40angular%2Fcore"+filename%3Apackage.json+stars%3A2&ref=advsearch&type=Code) which will show me repos having a package.json with @angular/core inside. But the star filter doesn't work and also the information about main language and stars are not being displayed next to it in the code search tab.

Finally i would love to combine these searches so i can search for Angular, React, React Native or Ionic Projects with a Demo (and maybe some other filters).

There are some lists (below) that list projects and tag them with the used language/framework but they are by far not complete, so it would be very useful to be able to search for them.

- [github.com/dkhamsing/open-source-ios-apps](https://github.com/dkhamsing/open-source-ios-apps)
- [github.com/pcqpcq/open-source-android-apps](https://github.com/pcqpcq/open-source-android-apps)
- [github.com/iampox/AndroidApps](https://github.com/iampox/AndroidApps)

**My question:**

Is there a software or website (or simply any way) to:

1. combine GitHub searches so i can find Projects that for example have a `package.json` file that contains `"@angular/core"` AND a `readme.md` file that contains for example the word `demo`?
2. Search for specific frameworks/libraries (like angular, react, ionic) used in the repository?
3. (find qualitative repositories...)?

Since I'm afraid there is none yet, can i use the GitHub API to combine two searches like `"@angular/core" filename:package.json` and `demo filename:readme.md` (or maybe search for the existance of a `gh_pages` branch) and list the repositories with stars, forks, used languages and so on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Some suitable workarounds:

With Github itself one can create clever queries or look up the topics on GitHub

#### Angular:

GitHub search query for repositories written with typescript, with the npm package `@angular/core` inside the `package.json` file, the word "demo" inside the readme and with more then 0 star:
[**GitHub query for Angular apps**](https://github.com/search?q=%22%40angular%2Fcore%22%20filename%3Apackage.json%20stars%3A%3E0%20demo%20in%3Areadme%20language%3Atypescript&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

I'm using some of the GitHub filters. First of all I searched for a angular typical package in the package.json, also for the word "demo" in the readme and I also filtered for repositories written in typescript.
You can filter for the `topic:angular` and for repos with more then 0 stars

- "@angular/core" filename:package.json
- demo in:readme
- language:typescript
- stars:>0
- topic:angular

[GitHub-Topic: Angular](https://github.com/topics/angular)

#### React (Native) with Typescript:

GitHub search query for repositories written with typescript, with the npm package `react-native` inside the `package.json` file and the word "demo" inside the readme:
[**GitHub query for ReactNative apps**](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22react-native%22%20filename%3Apackage.json%20demo%20in%3Areadme%20language%3Atypescript&type=Repositories)

[GitHub-Topic: React (Typescript)](https://github.com/topics/react?l=typescript)

## Finally:

In general it ***is(!)*** possible to do what I've been trying to acomplish. There is a project that mirrors Github and creates downloadable archives.
With BigQuery it is possible to analyze the repositories. At [**Source 1: GitHubArchive**](https://www.githubarchive.org/) and [**Source 2: ghtorrent**](http://ghtorrent.org/gcloud.html) you can read more about it.

It's very impressive what one can do with BigQuery and those data. There is an [**article**](https://medium.com/@hoffa/the-top-github-projects-per-country-92c275e19409) for example where BigQuery was used to find the top rated Repositories by country.
For this page BigQuery and the data from GitHubArchive was used too, to search for a language used, and filter for promising repositories (whatever promising means):
[gitmostwanted.com](http://gitmostwanted.com/?term=&lang=TypeScript)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the search criteria listed in the [official GitHub search guide](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/). Try setting the following attributes to fine tune your search.

- language - To set the language you want to search for (Ex : Java)
- topic - Any category you need (Ex : Angular)
- in:readme - To search for keywords in the README file (Ex : Android in:readme)
- in:name and in:description - Yes, you guessed it correct!

Comment: Thanks! Of course I've seen this page before. I did two searches: The first one to find angular projects with a demo in the readme. 

`"@angular/core" filename:package.json stars:>1 demo in:readme language:typescript`

that works somewhat. but the second search should find React native apps written in typescript and it only finds 5 repositories. 

`react-native-i18n filename:package.json demo in:readme language:typescript`

I'm sure there are more then 5 react native apps with a demo written in typescript on GitHub...

Comment: NightTrain Do you know how to do such whether a framework isn used inside one or more given repositories. I tried this `repo:ngx-formly/ngx-formly @angular/core filename:package.json` Didn't seem to work correctly.